# Alpha Beta Checkers- Same player always wins

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I am implementing a simple checkers AI using alpha-beta (minimax) search and have the implementation complete. I have two players, 1 and 2, but regardless of what depth I am using for my search (even if 1's depth > 2's depth), player 2 seems to win. I cannot seem to spot what I'm doing wrong. Do you have any thoughts as to what may be causing this? I am unsure if my implementation of alpha-beta search is entirely correct or if I am misunderstanding something about it. The game does run properly, just the results are not as expected. Please let me know if I can clarify this in any way. Your help is much appreciated!I have stripped away the GUI for purposes of this question, but it shouldn't affect anything. Thanks so much!

Board is a class that has a board attribute which is an 8x8 array of ints. 
0 empty space

1 white piece

2 red piece

3 white king

4 red king

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, id, depth):
        self.id = id
        self.depth = depth

    def board_eval(self, board):
        if len(board.get_moves(self.id)) == 0:
            return float('inf')*-1
        else:
            red = 0
            redK = 0
            white = 0
            whiteK = 0
            for r in range(len(board.board[0])):
                for c in range(len(board.board[0])):
                    if board.board[r][c]>0:
                        if board.board[r][c]==1:
                            white+=1
                        elif board.board[r][c]==2:
                            red+=1
                        elif board.board[r][c]==3:
                            whiteK+=1
                        elif board.board[r][c]==4:
                            redK+=1
            if self.id == 1:
                return white+whiteK-red-redK
            else:
                return red+redK-white-whiteK

    def minimax (self, board, depth, alpha, beta, player):
        board_value = self.board_eval(board)
        if depth == 0 or board_value == float('inf') or board_value == float('inf')*-1:
            return board_value
        if self.id == player:
            for poss_board in board.get_moves(player):
                alpha = max(alpha, self.minimax(poss_board, depth - 1, alpha, beta, (player%2)+1))
                if (alpha >= beta):
                    break
            return alpha
        else:
            for poss_board in board.get_moves(player): #TODO: should this be the other player? pretty sure no
                beta = min(beta, self.minimax(poss_board, depth - 1, alpha, beta, (player%2)+1))
                if (beta <= alpha):
                    break
            return beta


    def update_board(self, board):
        best_move = None
        best_score = float('inf') * -1
        for poss_move in board.get_moves(self.id):
            alpha = self.minimax(poss_move, self.depth-1, best_score, float('inf'), (self.id%2)+1)
            if best_move is None or alpha > best_score:
                best_move = poss_move
                best_score = alpha
            elif alpha == best_score and random.random() <= 0.3: #arbitrary randomness if multiple best moves
                best_move = poss_move
        return best_move

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.board = Board()
        self.p1 = Player(1, 4) #id, depth
        self.p2 = Player(2, 2) 
        self.height=800
        self.width=800
        self.win= GraphWin("Checkerboard", self.width, self.height)
        self.lag_win = GraphWin("Prev Board", self.width, self.height)
        self.lag_board = copy.deepcopy(self.board)
        self.cell_size = 50     # Height and width of checkerboard squares.
        self.offset_x = (self.width - 8*self.cell_size) / 2
        self.offset_y = (self.height - 8*self.cell_size) / 2

    def play(self):
        while True:
            self.board = self.p1.update_board(self.board)
            if self.board is None: #print("Game over, player 2 wins\n")
                return 2
            self.board = self.p2.update_board(self.board)
            if self.board is None: #print("Game over, player 1 wins\n")
                return 1

game = Game()
winner = game.play()
```

Answer (score -1):

Your board_eval appears to be returning a score relative to the player, but the minimax part of the code seems to be assuming an absolute score. What happens if you eliminate that `if` in `board_eval` and just `return white+whiteK-red-redK`?